# list view in Android (eclipse)

Tags: android-layout

I made list view with below code and I made array list in values. but I can't see my list when I run my program. What can I do?

```
public class ListView extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);;

        ArrayAdapter<string>adapter;
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<string>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,com.example.listview.R.array.countries);

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: Make sure this code actually runs. Set a breakpoint, check your manifest, try hardcoded strings, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This line is missing: setContentView(R.layout.simple_list_item_1); , no? Try this.